# SQL: Changing insert into query to accommodate differently-columned input tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given 2 temp tables:

## tmp

```
A  B
a1 b1
```

## tmp2

```
A  B  C
a2 b2 c2
```

Then, I created #tmp3 (from #tmp) and #tmp4 (and #tmp2) by simply renaming the columns A, B and C to COL1, COL2 and COL3 respectively.

I currently have:

```
Create table #tmp5 (
A varchar (100)
, B varchar (100
, C varchar (100)
)
    
Declare @column1 as varchar(256)
Declare @column2 as varchar(256)
Declare @column3 as varchar(256)

Select @column1 = column_name 
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME = #tmp2 and ORDINAL_POSITION = 1

Select @column2 = column_name 
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME = #tmp2 and ORDINAL_POSITION = 2

Select @column3 = column_name 
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME = #tmp2 and ORDINAL_POSITION = 3

Insert into #tmp5
    Select
    (Case when @column1 = 'A' then COL1
          when @column2 = 'A' then COL2
          when @column3 = 'A' then COL3 else NULL end) as A
    (Case when @column1 = 'B' then COL1
          when @column2 = 'B' then COL2
          when @column3 = 'B' then COL3 else NULL end) as B
    (Case when @column1 = 'C' then COL1
          when @column2 = 'C' then COL2
          when @column3 = 'C' then COL3 else NULL end) as C
    from #tmp4
```

I want to run the above queries so that it works for both types of inputs (#tmp with 2 columns and #tmp2 with 3 columns). Currently, the code only works for 3-columned tables because I get an error saying that COL3 is invalid. How would I change this to accommodate both types?

I tried to use if statements, case when statements to try this but none seem to work with the COL3 in the query... :(

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? maybe there is a better approach...

Comment: You could use an `if` to work out whether you need to run a two or three columned insert, then have two seperate inserts. (although I can't work out how you know that in the first place). _However_ what you're asking for is very strange and it's likely you have some kind of design issue or misunderstanding. That's why you should explain what you are actually trying to do

Comment: I’m trying to put these given temp tables (2 or 3 columns with differing column names) into one format so that I can merge/update another master table using these temp tables.